# zedgraph or equivalent for java

Tags: java, plot

I recently had a remarkably easy programming experience when I used zedGraph to add graph plotting to my father's ODE solving program in C#. He now wants me to do the same in java. Does anyone know if it's possible to use zedGraph in java, and if so how? Failing that, is there a similar package for java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a library witten for .net according to the [project description](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/), no you can't.

There are many alternatives: http://www.jroller.com/dgilbert/entry/19_free_open_source_chart